# python get request with params with no names

Tags: python, python-3.x, get, python-requests, web-api-testing

how properly to make a get request with no params names?
the api request must be like:

```
 url + '/smth/val1/val2'
```

usually do like so

```
payload = {p1:val1, p2:val2}
response = requests.get(url + '/smth', params=payload)
```

however, in that case I wrote the code:

```
requests.get(url + '/smth/{}/{}'.format(val1, val2))
```

is there any way to do it by using params key word?

Comment: `params` is designed to be used as parameters in a GET request. If the API has the parameters built into the URL itself then `params` won't work

Comment: As @NullUserException said, those parameters are outside the scope of the `requests` module. The way you're currently doing it (string formatting) is **just fine**. But if you want a more structured way of building URLs including those parameters, maybe have a look at the [`uritemplate`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uritemplate) package.